# Wallet download issues, cannot restore backup

Tags: synchronization, wallet-recovery, fraud

greetings everybody .....

I hope everybody is safe. I have a problem recovering my wallet, earlier this year there was a link on the website that make me able to access my wallet and recover the wallet in case of being lost.

I used the link  bitgowallet (dot) org and made a restore to my wallet and given to me all the data of the wallet and it contained 8.85 btc. And after entering the authorization password and safe words it gave me a copy of the date and install the wallet on my desktop. and then asked me to download all the blocks and files since 2009. This happened in last April, the download takes to long to be from 1%to 87% and didn't rais to 88% for 12 days, then 21 days to reach 93% then stop downloading. this problem recurrence for multiple times for three months. I keep trying till June, 16th,2020. the link worked fine and took to the end of July till we reach from 1% to 93 %  then my computer had technical issues and a fix and after fixing it I tried to use the link to re-download the data but it didn't work and not accessible.

I still have a previous copy of my wallet, which contains 8.58btc. I tried to redownload the data but it takes forever to reach 87% and never raise from this percentage not even 1% for over 3 days I keep waiting.

my question is why it takes to long to download the data even I have a fast internet connection and why it is never raised over 93% and why the link is not working? this issue cost me a lot of money and I bought a server for 350$ with a high specification to solve it but nothing work please I need your help I am in deep trouble.

regards.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain that BitGo never offered a rebranded Bitcoin Core wallet and it would be news to me if bitgowallet(dot)org was ever operated by BitGo. It looks like you installed some malware which likely stole your funds. If you were trying to recover funds from a BitGo wallet, I would suggest that you get in touch with support@bitgo.com.

As RedGrittyBrick stated in the comments:

> "It does look like bitgowallet.org was a scam/malware site unconnected with bitgo.com. Other people [report similar loss in April 2020](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5243940.0)"

Disclaimer: I am a former employee of BitGo, and I'm not speaking for BitGo.